# How to modify source code of a custom repository and use it in my python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, module

I have downloaded the github repo for the [Masked Rcnn](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) . Now I want to make a few changes to some of the scripts and change the source code to suit my applications. However when i change the code adn save it and import them in my program, its not updated. It still shows the same output. How do i modify the modules and reload them so that its updated when i import in my script?

So far, I was using jupyter notebook and I read about 'autoreload'.  However that didnt work. I am now directly runnign the pyfiles from the termical. I am running my program on an EC2 instance. My script is inside the github repo that I downloaded. I want to import the modified files

EDIT
I want to use the MRCNN repo from matterport to build a segmentation model. So I have cloned the repository from GitHub. Now, I have created my own py script which performs segmentation using the files from this repo. However, I want to make a few changes in some functions which are inside 'visualize.py' and 'model.py' which are a part of the repo. I have made the changes in my local copy of these files. And later imported these functions and modules into my script. However, the changes I made in 'visualize.py' and 'model.py' are not being reflected when I import these in my script. It is still performing the same operations that it initially used to. How do i update the changes I made in these modules so that i can use it in my script?

```
from mrcnn import utils
import mrcnn.model as modellib
from mrcnn import visualize
```

These are the files and modules

Comment: Please explain your workflow in more detail. Where and how do you change what? How do you import?

Comment: @KlausD. I have made the changes and explained the workflow please check it

Comment: Check your imports. See if `import mrcnn; print(mrcnn)` points to the right file.

Comment: <module 'mrcnn' from '/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/maskrcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mask_rcnn-2.1-py3.6.egg/mrcnn/__init__.py'> @KlausD. This is what its showing. How do I modify this? I have not seen this format before. Cant i update the py file directly and see changes?